# Remove a UIView from a UIScrollView and add to another custom UIView

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview, draggable

I have a UIScrollView that contains a few custom UIViews that I can drag around by implementing the touchesMoved method. However, I need to be able to drag this custom view out of the scroll view and have it added to a custom UIView that is to function as a sort of dock for the view that is being dragged.

How would I go about implementing this? As soon as I remove the custom draggable view from its superview, it disappears (understandably). Thank you.

Comment: @mundi is correct but also experiment with the the view.clipsToBounds = NO property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to have the view as a subview of the same view at the beginning and end of the drag.

In order to have it as a subview of another subview of this main view, you would have to destroy and recreate it at the appropriate place. You could do this both at the beginning and at the end of the drag process.